# Presto query raising error - StageStateMachine NullPointer when executing SELECT *

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet, presto

I'm loading parquet files from S3 to my Hive data warehouse, that is running inside an EMR machine :

`Release: emr-5.1.0`

`Hadoop distribution: Amazon 2.7.3`

`Applications: Hive 2.1.0, Spark 2.0.1, Presto 0.152.3)`

I can easily query the results inside hive using:

`select * from table_a`

However, when I try the same query using presto I get the following error :

```
ERROR   remote-task-callback-57 com.facebook.presto.execution.StageStateMachine Stage 20161117_211631_00018_29xwg.1 failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.RecordPageSource.getNextPage(RecordPageSource.java:124)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableScanOperator.getOutput(TableScanOperator.java:246)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:378)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processFor(Driver.java:301)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:622)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(TaskExecutor.java:529)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$Runner.run(TaskExecutor.java:665)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I know that my presto is able to query the hive table because I can do :

`select count(1) from table_a`

and

`select column_name from table_a`

What is the problem with my first select?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the file reader.  What file format are you using?

Comment: I'm using `PARQUET` files, but the problem persists with `ORC` files too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

When I defined my hive `create table` I added a field that doesn't exist on my files yet ( It will exist very soon ).

Using Presto I was able to `select column_name from table_a` for all fields of my table, excluding the missing one (what explains why `select * from table_a` didn't work).

Hive deals with the missing parameter on file by filling it with a `null` value on the query result. Presto tries to find the field, and raises a `NullPointerException`.

Machine versions:
`Hive 2.1.0, Spark 2.0.1, Presto 0.152.3`

**EDIT :**

Add these two flags (one for orc and another for parquet):

```
hive.parquet.use-column-names = true
hive.orc.use-column-names = true
```

to `hive.properties`:

```
/etc/presto/conf/catalog/hive.properties #path on emr
```